# Regarding URL redirecting in PHP application

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new in .HTACCESS, working on a PHP application(say test) in my system. When I click on any hyper link in the application its forward to the root directory (in XAMPP server). Its not redirecting to the appropriate page.

But `OnMouseOver` in the hyperlinks its showing correct path.

Comment: post the contents of you .htaccess file

Comment: mousehover's link can be changed, please check the source of the outputted `<a>`

Comment: RewriteEngine On                                              RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test$
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/test/$1 [R=301]                  This scripts I have used on .HTACCESS file

Comment: if you have Href for A tag as /page2.php then change it to page2.php

Comment: post the code of the hyperlink that you have problem with.